# MongoDB capped collection and monotically increasing index

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB capped collections, do I have the guarantee that the `_id` field is monotically increasing with the order of inserts? If not, how can I query for all the documents that were inserted after a given document? There shouldn't be any need for an index as I should be able to leverage their natural order.

Answer (score 3):

Part of ObjectId is a timestamp. So, if ObjectIds are always generated on the same machine (or otherwise time is consistent), then you are guaranteed monotonically increasing values. One caveat, though: timestamp is in seconds, not milliseconds. So, within the same second order of values is not guaranteed.

Capped collections support a special sorting option: [`$natural`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order). That means that documents will be returned in insertion order.

You can combine this with [tailable cursors](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) to continually fetch newly inserted documents without using any indexes (if that's what you're after).

Comment: Ok, but how do I query starting from a document with specific ObjectId? I'm actually looking for a solution to restart a new tailable cursor after the previous one has gone bad, where it left off.

Comment: Find it and then sort. I haven't tried myself, but should work. `db.cappedCollection.find({_id: {$gte: oid}}).sort({$natural:1}).limit(50)`

Comment: You said there is no guarantee the OID follows the natural order, so that query is not gonna work.

Comment: You either need to include a createdAt timestamp in your documents to query on, or if you want to use the $natural insertion order, you'll need to fetch all the from the database and do the filter client-side.