# How does MongoDB sort records when no sort order is specified?

Tags: mongodb

When we run a Mongo find() query without any sort order specified, what does the database internally use to sort the results?

According to the [documentation on the mongo website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order):

> When executing a find() with no parameters, the database returns
>   objects in forward natural order.
>
> For standard tables, natural order is not particularly useful because,
>   although the order is often close to insertion order, it is not
>   guaranteed to be. However, for Capped Collections, natural order is
>   guaranteed to be the insertion order. This can be very useful.

However for standard collections (non capped collections), what field is used to sort the results?
Is it the **_id** field or something else?

**Edit:**

Basically, I guess what I am trying to get at is that if I execute the following search query:

```
db.collection.find({"x":y}).skip(10000).limit(1000);
```

At two different points in time: **t1** and **t2**, will I get different result sets:

1. When there have been no additional writes between t1 & t2?
2. When there have been new writes between t1 & t2?
3. There are new indexes that have been added between t1 & t2?

I have run some tests on a temp database and the results I have gotten are the same (**Yes**) for all the 3 cases - but I wanted to be sure and I am certain that my test cases weren't very thorough.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

#### What is the default sort order when none is specified?

The default internal sort order (or [natural order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order)) is an **undefined** implementation detail. Maintaining order is extra overhead for storage engines and MongoDB's API does not mandate predictability outside of an explicit `sort()` or the special cases of [clustered collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/clustered-collections/) and fixed-sized [capped collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/).

For typical workloads it is desirable for the storage engine to try to reuse available preallocated space and make decisions about how to most efficiently store data on disk and in memory. Without any query criteria, results will be returned by the storage engine in [natural order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-natural-order) (aka **in the order they are found**). Result order may coincide with insertion order but this behaviour is not guaranteed and cannot be relied on (aside from clustered or capped collections).

Some examples that may affect storage (natural) order:

- WiredTiger uses a different representation of documents on disk versus the in-memory cache, so natural ordering may change based on internal data structures.
- The original MMAPv1 storage engine (removed in MongoDB 4.2) allocates record space for documents based on padding rules. If a document outgrows the currently allocated record space, the document location (and natural ordering) will be affected. New documents can also be inserted in storage marked available for reuse due to deleted or moved documents.
- Replication uses an [idempotent oplog](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) format to apply write operations consistently across replica set members. Each replica set member maintains local data files that can vary in natural order, but will have the same data outcome when oplog updates are applied.

#### What if an index is used?

If an index is used, documents will be returned in the order they are found (which does necessarily match insertion order or I/O order). If more than one index is used then the order depends internally on which index first identified the document during the de-duplication process.

If you want a predictable sort order you **must** include an explicit `sort()` with your query and have unique values for your sort key.

#### How do capped collections maintain insertion order?

The implementation exception noted for natural order in capped collections is enforced by their special [usage restrictions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#restrictions-and-recommendations): documents are stored in insertion order but existing document size cannot be increased and documents cannot be explicitly deleted. Ordering is part of the capped collection design that ensures the oldest documents "age out" first.

#### Clustered Collections (MongoDB 5.3+)

Starting in MongoDB 5.3, it is possible to create a clustered collection where documents are ordered by `_id` index key values. The [`clusteredIndex`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#std-label-db.createCollection.clusteredIndex) must be declared when the collection is created. Clustered collections have some [usage limitations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/clustered-collections/#limitations) but can improve performance for queries like range scans and equality comparisons on the clustered index key.

Comment: So does this mean that if I run the same find command: db.collection.find({"x":y}).skip(20000).limit(1000) at two different points in time, I'll get different result sets? What happens if the there have been no writes in between the two commands?

Comment: @saurabhj: Added some examples that will affect natural order.  If documents have been moved/deleted you may get different result sets.  If there have been no document inserts/updates/deletes you should get the same result.  Adding indexes does not affect the location of documents on disk.

Comment: Should also add the caveat that if you are using [replication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication) the natural ordering can vary between replica set members.

Comment: Does anyone know how to force any of the 2 points commented here? We tried modifying documents but they're still returned in their insertion order... I'm curious about whether the natural order can be different from the insertion order.

Comment: Enforcing a default order (eg `{createdAt: -1}`) is necessary to implement Optimistic UI patterns (updating lists of data in the cache without waiting for the server response after a create/update/delete).  Otherwise you can't match the client-side optimistic order and the server response order.

Comment: see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/clustered-collections/

Answer (score 16):

It is returned in the stored order (order in the file), but it is not guaranteed to be that they are in the inserted order. They are not sorted by the _id field. Sometimes it can be look like it is sorted by the insertion order but it can change in another request. It is not reliable.