# Disable sorting in sailsjs query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I have some id's stored in array `locationIds` that is already sorted in a way I want it. But with the below codes, I am getting the response in sails default sorted order.

```
var locationIds = []; // pushing id's in it
Locations.find({ id: locationIds }).paginate({ page: page, limit: limit }).exec(function(err, sortedLocations) {
  // need the response in the same order as in locationIds
});
```

Is there any way that I can disable this default sorting or any other possibilities? Need help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you doesn't specify any order in MongoDB you have no guarantee in which order you will get records. You should get it in **natural order** but you cant be 100% sure. See [How does MongoDB sort records when no sort order is specified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599069/how-does-mongodb-sort-records-when-no-sort-order-is-specified)

Comment: Alright, so instead of disabling it, is there any other way for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you don't specify a sort order, there's no guarantee what order the results will come in.  If you have a specific order in mind that is independent of any of the existing fields, then the best approach is to add an `order` field to the records that you can use to order them manually, and then sort on that.