# mongodump and mongorestore changes order of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I am using mongodump command to dump mongodb data, but when I am restoring it using mongorestore it changes order of documents (order in which documents was inserted), What might be the issue? Is there any way by which I can preserve insertion order?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599069/how-does-mongodb-sort-records-when-no-sort-order-is-specified

Answer (score 8):

You can use **"maintainInsertionOrder"** to preserve the insertion order. The default is False.

> --maintainInsertionOrder
>
> Default: False
>
> If specified, mongorestore inserts the documents in the order of their
>   appearance in the input source, otherwise mongorestore may perform the
>   insertions in an arbitrary order.

Comment: It is not working, actually, I have checked my dump records using "bsondump collection.bson > collection.json" and I found that this dump doesn't maintain insertion order.