# Why aggregate() in Mongodb returning results in reverse order?

Tags: java, mongodb

```
Bson group = group("$NAME",sum("amount", "$amount"));

        AggregateIterable <Document> output = collection.aggregate(asList(group));

        MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor = output.iterator();
        while(cursor.hasNext()){ 
            System.out.println(cursor.next());

        }
    }
```

The above code returning results in reverse order

Comment: If you haven't [specified an order yourself](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), then [you might get the results back in any order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11599283/174843).

Comment: yeah,It worked by sorting both fields i.e.                                               Bson sort = sort(new Document("_id", 1).append("amount", -1));

Comment: Can you have a look at the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42862170/7720299) @http://stackoverflow.com/users/174843/vince-bowdren

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does MongoDB sort records when no sort order is specified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599069/how-does-mongodb-sort-records-when-no-sort-order-is-specified)

Comment: I want to retrieve all the columns of a collection, I want to perform select * from tablename group by Name). Can you please go through the link in the above comment and let me know how to do? @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/174843/vince-bowdren