# How to insert a document at first position in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

By default, mongodb adds documents to the end of collection. However, I want them to be added at the first position in the collection. The code I have is,

```
  MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
  DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
  DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("lwjsons");        
  BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
  collection.insert(dbObject);
```

Comment: See [How does MongoDB sort records when no sort order is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599283/2313887) which should inform that there is "no order of documents at all". If you want things to *come out in a certain order* then you pick a property ( optionally created if you must ) and **sort** on it. But there is no such thing as "record order" or "insertion order". ( with the exception of capped collections, but the answer does say that )

Comment: so, what would be the code for this?

Comment: You can use `sort` when finding data.

Comment: no, I am not finding anything. I just want the record to be inserted at the first position rather than last

Comment: you are inserting to a collection in the database. This is not like Array `push` or array `unshift` in javascript. 

You can use `db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1})`

Comment: @NeilLunn see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/clustered-collections/

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` when querying.

Just use `db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1})`.

You are saving documents to collection. It is not like `push` or `unshift` in javascript.

Comment: this query seems to work `db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)` However, I don't want to query but actually make a record insert at first position, rather than last.

Comment: You are simply seeing the documents in the collection. What is the need for inserting into first position ?

Comment: that's my requirement to insert a given record to first place

Comment: please delete your answer