# MongoDB: imported documents do not keep the same order if were inserted through insertMany()

Tags: mongodb

If through *mongo shell* is used the following (for few documents 50 for example)

```
db.<collection>.insertMany(
[
  {
    "name": "some name 1",
    ...
  },
  {
   "name": "some name 2",
    ...
  },
  ...
  {
    "name": "some name N",
    ...
  }
])
```

I can confirm that through `db.<collection_name>.find()` the documents are shown in **the exact same order** how they were declared and inserted through `db.<collection>.insertMany()`. Until here it is expected and is fine for me.

I did realize the following, if the collection is empty, and if the same content shown above - *keeping the same the order* - is declared as follows within the `import.js` file for importation purposes:

```
[
  {
    "name": "some name 1",
    ...
  },
  {
   "name": "some name 2",
    ...
  },
  ...
  {
    "name": "some name N",
    ...
  }
]
```

Therefore, is used *the same content and order* but `db.<collection>.insertMany()` was removed/ignored.

So, then if is executed through the console/terminal the following command:

```
mongoimport --db some_db \
            --collection collection_name \
            --file /path/import.json \
            --jsonArray
```

I can confirm the importation process is accomplished but if `db.<collection_name>.find()` is executed then the documents are shown in a **different** order how they were declared and inserted through `db.<collection>.insertMany()` as the first approach.

How fix this? It is problematic for aggregations how `$first` and `$last`

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599283/2282634

Comment: @Joe The point is accomplish the importation process but keeping and respecting the order of the documents declared within the .json file - seems your link is mostly based after of the importation

Comment: The point is the order that documents are returned is not explicitly defined.  You may find that it happens to be insertion order for some cases, but that should not be relied upon.  If you need the documents returned in a particular order, sort them.  If you really need the insertion order to be honored, use the maintainInsertionOrder command line option.

Comment: Interesting, I used the `db.<collection>.insertMany()` approach many times and even in many instances and always the order is respected. Let me research about the `maintainInsertionOrder` option. Thanks

Comment: @Joe the `--maintainInsertionOrder` parameter works how expected, put your answer to to mark it how solved. Thanks for the quick and polite support!