# MongoDB Fetching Data in Different Orders Despite Sequential Insertion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am experiencing an issue with fetching data from MongoDB. I've noticed that even though I insert a large collection of data in a specific order, the results I get from fetching seem to be in a different order each time, despite using the same query. How can I ensure that the fetched data retains the order in which it was inserted? Are there any specific considerations or settings in MongoDB that I need to be aware of to address this issue ?

the 'find()' method in MongoDB return data in different orders for consecutive queries, even though I've inserted the data sequentially? How can I ensure consistent order when using the 'find()' method to fetch data?"

Comment: In which order do you insert the data? Do you have a specific field (e.g. a timestamp) that you use to determine the order?

Comment: use a {$sort: fieldname}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does MongoDB sort records when no sort order is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599069/how-does-mongodb-sort-records-when-no-sort-order-is-specified)